# Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," for liquibase loadUpdateData with data using quotchar

Tags: liquibase

I'm getting this error

```
mental-app_1            |      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
mental-app_1            |   Position: 55 [Failed SQL: DO
mental-app_1            | $$
mental-app_1            | BEGIN
mental-app_1            | UPDATE public.training SET active_since = , active_until = , conditions = 'obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];', game_id = 28, identificator = '3_1', subject_id = 1 WHERE id = 1;
mental-app_1            | IF not found THEN
mental-app_1            | INSERT INTO public.training (id, active_since, active_until, identificator, conditions, game_id, subject_id) VALUES (1, , , '3_1', 'obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];', 28, 1);
mental-app_1            | END IF;
mental-app_1            | END;
mental-app_1            | $$
mental-app_1            | LANGUAGE plpgsql;]
```

when executing the below part of changeset

```
<loadUpdateData onlyUpdate="true" quotchar='"'
            file="config/liquibase/data/training.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="training"  primaryKey="id">
            <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="active_since" type="datetime"/>
            <column name="active_until" type="datetime"/>
            <column name="identificator" type="string"/>
            <column name="conditions" type="string"/>
            <column name="game_id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="subject_id" type="numeric"/>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-loadcolumn - JHipster (and/or extensions) can add load columns here, do not remove-->
        </loadUpdateData>
```

for this kind of data

```
id;active_since;active_until;identificator;conditions;game_id;subject_id
1;;;3_1;"obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];";28;1
```

What is wrong with changeset set up of with dataset?
Change to

```
id;active_since;active_until;identificator;conditions;game_id;subject_id
1;"";"";3_1;"obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];";28;1
```

causes the same. That is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you tried to set the fields active_since and active to NULL instead to "" to make the syntax of the generated sql valid?

Comment: I have succeed with removing that columns from the dataset and removing them from the changeset conf. But until I've got quoted string for conditions column like this `"obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];"` it was ok with empty `active_since` and `active_to`. So, coexistence of `"obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];"` and empty for that fields are critical there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of it is still unclear, why the exception is thrown, I have succeed with removing `active_since` and `active_to` columns from the dataset and removing them from the changeset conf. But until I've got quoted string for conditions column like this `"obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];"` it was ok with empty `active_since` and `active_to`. So, coexistence of `"obj.trainingColumns = [1,2];"` and empty for that fields is critical there